# Kurento : Audio lost for 4-5seconds when someone joins a meeting room

Tags: kurento

I have been working on custom kurento group call application, the issue which we are facing right now is that when someone tries to join a meeting there are 2-3 users are already in the room, whole rooms audio is lost for couple of seconds.

P.S: No custom modules applied to the room.
     Application server is hosted on AWS t2.large instance and KMS is hosted in a dedicated in house server with i7 processor and 16gb ram.

**EDIT 1:**
CPU usage is at  30-40%

Ram is about 2-2.5gb out of 16gb

`top` command shows kurento media server using 245-300% cpu

Comment: Did you check the load when this happens?

Comment: about 13gb ram is free but `top` command gave cpu usage 245-300% for kurento

Comment: Have you checked with any other instance, like m3.large? We use that, and haven't seen that issue.

Comment: I've never seen this, to be honest. Does it happen only with 2-3 users? If you go higher what happens?

Comment: max we have reached a point of 6 users in the same room, after which video is not visible to some users of other users
We have observed this with minimum of 2-3 users, when 4th person joins there is a mute in the room audio...

Comment: That's weird. I take it you are using the latest release of KMS, 6.4.0 as of now. Did you check with different servers? Perhaps deploying in AWS?

Comment: yes we are using kms 6.4.0, I will try deploying on aws server and check the result

Comment: was the audio quality improved for group audio call for anyone.